# Ios Sharpoint integration [sharpoint as a backend]

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, sharepoint

I have **sharpoint service in my backend** and i want to use that in my IOS application .

In which term that will give me response to support IOS in **XML or JSON** ?

I am newbei in Sharpont integration .

Can Anyone support me in this Problem ?

Need Some **Steps How can I use my website Sharepoint respomce in IOS** with which responce it Supports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this project, it supports SharePoint 2013 RestAPI, however it uses Claims protocol for authentication which more suitable MS SharePoint Online.
https://github.com/jimmywim/SPRestAPI

Answer (score 0):

If you have SharePoint 2010, you are lucky, since you can use the "Restful API" of Sharepoint - sending HTTP requests and receiving jSON or XML data in response. You will find a lot of answers in the document here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx

Comment: Thanks . I have SharePoint 2013 as a backhand . Do u have any idea how do I use Restful API in that ...

Answer (score 0):

Addition info with above answer:

By Default SPRESTQuery class provides the response in XML format. If you want to get response in JSON format, then write this line in executeQuery method

Line need to add:

[apiRequest setValue:@"application/json;odata=verbose" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];